# Passing runtime parameters to a spring boot based REST service deployed as a war file in tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, tomcat8

I have a springboot based REST service that is deployed as a war file in tomcat. For my debugging, I had some environment specific parameters such as database username and password.  For debugging, I have the values in application.properties.

This service will be deployed in AWS in an ec2 instance using tomcat.  What is the best way to pass these  type of parameters.  All the examples I have looked at in spring documentation assume a jar file being run form command line but I have not seen any examples of passing these variables to a war file deployed in a webserver.

Thanks for your help.

Waqar

Answer (score 0):

You can externalize your data store credentials from spring boot application by making as system environment variables. Once you launch as EC2 instance you can specify in user data scripts. In application.properties, you can get the environment variables as `database.username: ${DATABASE_USER}`